# LinqExpression nested property, compare to string

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am working on implementing a generic pattern to be able to filter a where clause.  The basic use case is our API's accept a query parameter called `?filterBy:AddressState:VA` .

I'm trying to create something that will be able to generically append clauses to an `IQueryable`.   Basically each API needs to create a dictionary of key/`Expressions` that will do the look up of the property to compare the right side of the `filterBy` e.g. `VA`..  Here is what I have so far but its currently crashing with the error

> "The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[Framework.Models.User,System.String]' and 'System.String'.",

Example dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<User, Object>>> FILTER_BY = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<User, Object>>>()  
{
    { "addressstate", (x) => x.Address.State},   
};
```

Call to use extension method:

```
baseQ = baseQ.FilterBy(filterBy, FILTER_BY);
```

Extension method:

```
 public static string GetPropertySymbol<T, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
 {
      return String.Join(".",
          ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).GetMembersOnPath()
             .Select(m => m.Member.Name)
             .Reverse());
 }
```

Helper methods to translate the nested select to a strong

```
 static Expression CreateExpression(Type type, string propertyName)
 {
   var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
   Expression body = param;
   foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
   {
      body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
   }
   return Expression.Lambda(body, param);
 }
```

Utility function that is broken.

```
  public static IQueryable<T> FilterBy<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> query, string filterBy, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>> filterExpressions)
 {
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterBy))
   {
     //parse on ':' throw argument if there is not two.
     var split = filterBy.Split(':');
     var key = split[0];
     var right = string.Join("", split.Skip(1));

     var expression  =filterExpressions.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Key == key.ToLower());
     if (expression.Key != null)
     {
        var parameterItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
        var rightExp = Expression.Constant(right);

        var left = CreateExpression(typeof(T),expression.Value.GetPropertySymbol()); 

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(
                    left,
                     rightExp
                 ),
                 parameterItem
         );
        return query.Where(lambda);
     }
  }
  return query;
}
```

Once I get a basic string comparison working, I might actually see about doing other types of constants strings, ints, date time.  but I can get by short term with strings.

Let me know if you have any other questions.   I had tried a different approach where i try to wrap the existing function basically called Invoke and then generated a new one, but it resulted in entity framework throwing an exception about .Invoke not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method

```
static Expression CreateExpression(Type type, string propertyName)
```

creates a separate parameter. You need to modify it to receive the parameter as argument and return just the body (instead of lambda), so here

```
var left = CreateExpression(typeof(T),expression.Value.GetPropertySymbol());
```

you can call it like this

```
var left = CreateExpression(parameterItem,expression.Value.GetPropertySymbol());
```

The modified function could be like this

```
static Expression CreateExpression(ParameterExpression param, string propertyName)
{
    Expression body = param;
    foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
    }
    return body;
}
```

or simple

```
static Expression CreateExpression(Expression target, string memberPath)
{
    return memberPath.Split('.').Aggregate(target, Expression.PropertyOrField);
}
```

Comment: Same result...  as above.  The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[Framework.Models.User,System.String]' and 'System.String'.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to remove the lambda creation. See the updated answer.

Comment: you rock!  It worked.   Just testing to make sure it pushed it to the DB and then i will accept!

Comment: Just realized my example above wasn't complete.  I wanted to be able to pass expressions like : `   { "addressstate", (x, value ) => x.Address.State == value},`    and then be able to swap out value...

Comment: Ill update the question name and then open a new one because you did fix my issue.